# How to avoid the Null Pointer Exception from crashing my app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**ret_idx** might be null for a new user since its entry in database is not made. So whenever the app detects **ret_idx** is **null**, it shows the *java.lang.NullPointerException*. How do I avoid this exception from crashing my app, considering **ret_idx** might go **null** in several cases.

`String ret_idx=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();`

Comment: What do you mean by avoid this error? If the value might go null and you are getting null then I\it is not an error. Wherever you are using ret_idx next, there check for null value like if(ret_idx != null) then do something you want to do.

Comment: @SurabhiChoudhary I have tried both if(ret_idx!=null) and if(!ret_idx.isEmpty()) and they work fine. Problem is in the assignment of ret_idx to null and checking if(ret_idx==null) or if(ret_idx.isEmpty()). App crashes when null is retrieved from the database and assigned to String ret_idx.

Comment: in all honesty, the best way to handle a possible null pointer exception is to make sure the object you're using is not null when you're using it.

Comment: Absolutely @a_local_nobody, but what else can I expect from a non-existent record in my database?  Non-existent record would always give a null I assume...

Comment: To avoid a NullPointException we use a the Try-Catch-concept. Sometimes even Try-Catch-Finally. You should read more about Exceptions and how to handle them. The Internet is full with tutorials and information about Exceptions. Basic knowledge.

Comment: Yes @TheScribbler2019 I've tried it, but there is a problem with the variables. They are not found outside try{ }.

Comment: re: *App crashes when null is retrieved from the database and assigned to String ret_idx.*   Assignment of null does not cause that exception.  Quite likely your call to ```child()``` returns null, and then you try to dereference it to call ```getValue()```.  Don't do that. Check for null first.

Comment: @TheScribbler2019 To avoid NullPointerExceptions you should **not** use try-catch, instead you should null-checks where necessary (or try and avoid null entirely).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your input data is null or not and if not then assign it to ret_idx.

```
if(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue() != null){
   String ret_idx=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
}
```

Comment: It's inefficiently doing the same database lookup twice. Save the first return value.